# Java unexpected console output

Tags: java, printing

How can I tabulate my output so that the calculations line up with Celsius and Fahrenheit?

Also, how do I display a number like `183.20000000000002` more naturally?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double cel = 0;
    double fahrenheit =cel * 1.8+ 32;

    int i;
    System.out.println();// blank line
    System.out.print("Hello ");// output line
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("This Program will show temperature conversions from 0-100\nThen in reverse \nCelsius              Fahrenheit");

    for (i = 0; i <25; i++){    
        cel =cel+ 4;
        fahrenheit =cel * 1.8+ 32;
        System.out.println(+ cel + "                  " + fahrenheit);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the netbeans tag got to do with this?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't see the connection between the duplicate answer and this? This seems to be asking about the best way to format a number not why a floating point representation doesn't match expectations...

Comment: Considering using something like [`System.out.printf`](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's probably just me, but I'm not seeing it.  Not sure how it's suppose to answer the OP's question, but I could be reading them both wrong

Comment: @MadProgrammer I edited it to make it not what I would consider a duplicate and voted to reopen. At a minimum, I think it's clearly not a duplicate now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `String#format` or `System.out.printf` to generate formatted output, for example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double cel = 0;
    double fahrenheit = cel * 1.8 + 32;

    int i;
    System.out.println();// blank line
    System.out.print("Hello ");// output line
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("This Program will show temperature conversions from 0-100\nThen in reverse");
    System.out.printf("%s | %s%n", "Celsius", "Fahrenheit");

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        cel = cel + 4;
        fahrenheit = cel * 1.8 + 32;
        System.out.printf(" %6.2f | %6.2f%n", cel, fahrenheit);
    }
}
```

Which outputs...

```
Hello 
This Program will show temperature conversions from 0-100
Then in reverse
Celsius | Fahrenheit
   4.00 |  39.20
   8.00 |  46.40
  12.00 |  53.60
  16.00 |  60.80
  20.00 |  68.00
  24.00 |  75.20
  28.00 |  82.40
  32.00 |  89.60
  36.00 |  96.80
  40.00 | 104.00
  44.00 | 111.20
  48.00 | 118.40
  52.00 | 125.60
  56.00 | 132.80
  60.00 | 140.00
  64.00 | 147.20
  68.00 | 154.40
  72.00 | 161.60
  76.00 | 168.80
  80.00 | 176.00
  84.00 | 183.20
  88.00 | 190.40
  92.00 | 197.60
  96.00 | 204.80
 100.00 | 212.00
```

Check out [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) for more details about the available formatting options

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class to ensure that only the right number of decimals show up. [Floating Points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) (including doubles, which are just "double wide" floating points) use a special binary representation and some decimals don't always round correctly. Using Formatting classes ensures that you don't output a number that is longer than a user expected (e.g. telling a user a price is $1.0000001 wouldn't be good practice--its part of the reason why floating points are poor choices for things like money).

Example:

```
double data = 0.08d+0.02d;
//The # means "optional digit", the zeros mean mandatory
//e.g. 4 formatted with "#.##" would be "4", but with 
//"#.00" would be "4.00"
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(fmt.format(data));
```

To address the second part of your question (although that should be in a separate question altogether), I recommend you review `printf()`. [Here](http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf) is a good guide on its use.

Comment: Consider `"#.00"` to require two decimal places.